# .Net 1.1 upgrade to .Net 2 - Does it still use the .Net 1.1 framework

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, upgrade

We have recently taken on support of a web application that was written many years ago and targeted v1.1 of the .net framework. It runs on Windows Server 2003/IIS 6 environment.

After looking at the configuration of the site in IIS the target framework is set to 2.0.

Given that extended support for .net 1.1 will cease in October of this year (http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=1249) I am trying to ascertain whether the site will still use any of the .net 1.1 framework assemblies given that the application is built and compiled in Visual Studio 2003.

I am assuming this is the case because although ASP.net 2 is set as the target framework
in IIS (and therefore the aspet_isapi.dll invoked is the .net 2 one etc) the assembly is a .net 1.1 assembly and will therefore still use the 1.1 framework. However, is this assumption actually true?

The website only has another year or so to live before being replaced by a new solution entirely so I would prefer not to upgrade it if possible and run the risks such changes bring with them.

However, we obviously can't run something on an unsupported version of the framework if any element of if that framework is actually being used.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**Update:**

It would seem that .net 1.1 is a core component of WS2k3 so you can't just uninstall it. I could have attempted to remove the ASP.net component but I don't think that would fully uninstall everything and given that the dev environment is shared I can't risk causing any issues right now.

However I have previously set everything up on my local machine (Windows 7/IIS 7), so I changed the application pool to point at .net 2 (it was already running in classic pipeline mode), uninstalled .net frameworks 1 and 1.1 and cleaned up the files left behind afterwards.

The result was that the site ran absolutely fine, which would suggest in an IIS 7 environment at least that I don't need to worry about upgrading given we are running under .net 2 within IIS.

It's not an ideal test as it isn't a mimick of our live environment. I'm going to post a question on MSDN and asp.net to see if any Microsoft folks can add anything more definitive. I will post back here with any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this questions after reading this link (provided as an answer to [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1912361/5423203.aspx/1?p=True&t=635066994294283816) question on the ASP.net forums)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994381.aspx

Under "Application Load Mechanisms and Possible Issues" it states:

> By default, an application built using the .NET Framework will run using the version of the Framework it was built against if that version is installed on the computer

It then goes on to detail (for .net 1.1 and 2.0 at least) when a particular version of the framework is used.

Essentially, because our server has both 1.1 and 2.0 installed the application will still be using version 1.1. If 1.1 was not installed then it would run by default under 2.0, which explains why the web application still worked after I uninstalled .net 1.0 and 1.1 from my local machine.

Given that the live server is W2K3 and I can't remove .net 1.1, I will be rebuilding my application to target .net 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just because official support will end doesn't mean Microsoft will pull the plug and force an uninstall of .NET 1.1 via Windows Update. It only means that:

- if a gaping hole in the framework's security is ever found, they'll not fix it;
- There won't be redistributables for the next versions of Windows, and the next version of IIS won't run it.

So the application will still run in a year. If you leave the server alone, the application might run until the machine breaks of old age.

So my suggestion is relax, and focus more on the new solution.

Comment: Hi Renan - thanks for your response. I appreciate that, however what happens if there is a big gaping hole found? I'd rather not be in that position given that this is a public facing site.

Comment: If there's a big gaping hole anywhere, chances are it's in the application and not in the Framework. .NET 1.1 has been around for a decade, and countless systems have been made using it. If there was any ten-year-old, unfixed gaping hole in the framework itself, we would have noticed the rains of frogs and the river waters turned into blood.

Comment: You may well be right, although a quick Google brings up vulnerabilities marked as critical that were patched much more recently.

Comment: You know what? You're right. I just checked, and there are fixes for privilege elevation and remote code execution going as recently as 2012, and that's a one minute check. I suddenly feel the need to check my old apps too. On the bright side, whenever I had to transition from 1.0 or 1.1 to 2.0, it was not a hard thing to do, even with some really big systems.

Comment: I agree, the update shouldn't introduce any issues but it's the testing to make sure that it doesn't that's time consuming (and also you can never guarantee that something will go amiss even after the most thorough testing). That's why I was wondering (given our live environment is already configured to use .net 2) if I need to bother at all? I've just had the idea of uninstalling .net 1.1 from one of our dev environments and seeing what happens.

Comment: I would do that. I'm also wishing you good luck. Also please do come back and tell what happens when you do that.